# Powerlifting and Olympic Lifting: How much does height affect strength?

Tags: strength, strength-training, powerlifting, olympic-weightlifting

For powerlifting and olympic lifting, the height of a person obviously has some affect. A taller person has a longer bar path which takes more power to travel. The height of a person can also affect their leverages and abilities.

Given two people with the same build and training, how much does a person's height affect their strength? Has there been any good studies on this subject?

The question deals with raw totals and not wilks or percentage of weight.

Comment: I also realize those are two very different sports, so if this question is too broad, I will refine it to one of them.

Answer (score 3):

I can't speak for weightlifting as I'm by no means educated on it all.

In regards to powerlifting though, there is a general theory of 'you are x height so should compete in x weight class'. It's not to suggest if you are 6'4 you can ONLY be competitive in the super heavy weight class it's just a general observation of majority bigger athletes usually compete heavier as they are bigger humans overall.

Honestly I don't think height is that much of a  factor, I personally feel its body proportion. It's very apparent with different athletes, Layne Norton's squat for example.